# Uninstalled Accountability Software Still Encumbering Internet Connection

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, google-chrome, internet

Hey so I have had connection problems for over a year now on my 2014 Macbook Pro, and after trying literally everything Google could point me towards I have found a possible culprit - but obviously I have no idea how to fix it.  After getting the computer I installed an accountability software called X3Watch that sends reports of flagged websites to a friend, to deter me from going to illicit websites and stuff.  When my computer started having problems (it was only slow when using anything requiring an Internet connection) I uninstalled the program thinking it was interfering with the browser.  It didn't fix anything, but apparently I was right.  Here is what I found in my system log when I try to connect to any website:

```
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: OPEN SQLITE
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: Found version record
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: Get format for User blacklist http://www.x3watch.com/api/v1/blacklists.json?auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: Get format for User whitelist http://www.x3watch.com/api/v1/whitelists.json?auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: settingsURL string http://www.x3watch.com/api/v1/users/show.json?auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: heatbeast post format auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP&source=MacBook Pro&source_id=C02N2DQJFH00
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: RECEIVED DATA FOR ENDPOINT (http://www.x3watch.com/api/v1/users/show.json?auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP)
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: blocking value 1
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: RECEIVED DATA FOR ENDPOINT (http://www.x3watch.com/api/v1/whitelists.json?auth_token=CziY4zduXqQZKoF47TuP): {"errors":"Feature requires premium subscription"}
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: JSON : {
        errors = "Feature requires premium subscription";
    }
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro x3d[960]: +[SBJsonStreamWriter initialize] NSCache supported
Apr 27 22:42:00 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[977]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash.DirectoryService
```

So it's obviously still going through this super long process every time it loads a webpage, sometimes hundreds of times if there are lots of links on a page.  No wonder it loads slowly.  But my question is: How do I fix this process.  I recently reinstalled my OS just to see, but it didn't do any good.  I'd like to avoid restoring to factory settings, but I am not opposed if it is the only way.  Any other thoughts on how to get my computer to stop going through this process?

Comment: How did you uninstall the app? Just by deleting it or with the AppleScript uninstaller?

Comment: Most likely there is a LaunchAgent .plist file in /Users/<your_username>/Library/LaunchAgents . Check in that folder for a .plist file with a name that resembles x3d and chuck it in the trash, then restart.

Comment: IconDaemon you were spot on! Found a plist in my LaunchDaemons folder. So far my laptop has been super fast since the restart. THANK YOU THIS WAS A HUGE FRUSTRATION FOR ME